# Wierd effects with JavaScript gauge

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making a guage in javascript for a project at work and based on the value of the guage, the whole thing should change color and it does, however the colors go nuts on some values and I can't figure out why this is going on.

Normaly the behaviour should be the following:

- Between 0% and 25% - Red
- Between 26% and 75% - Yellow
- Between 76% and 100% - Green

When the code runs it apparently behaves as it should except...

- If it's between 3% and 9% it yellow (should be red)
- If it's 100% it's red (should be green)
- If it's 0% it's red, but the bar does a 360 degree spin... wut?

I have looked at the code for over 2 hours and I cannot find the logic in why the bugs, I was wondering is someone here might see something I missed.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300">
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #333;
}
/*Centering the gauge*/
#canvas {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 100px auto;
}
/*Custom font for numbers*/
@font-face {
    font-family: "bebas";
    src: url("http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/fonts/BebasNeue.otf");
}
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function(){
//canvas initialization
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
//dimensions
var W = canvas.width;
var H = canvas.height;
//Variables
var red = "25%";
var yellow = "75%";
var green = "100%";
var degrees = 0;
var new_degrees = 724;
var difference = 0;
var color = "lightgreen"; 
var bgcolor = "#222";
var redcolor = "orangered";
var yellowcolor = "goldenrod";
var greencolor = "lightgreen";
var text;
var animation_loop, redraw_loop;
var startAngle = 1 * Math.PI;
var endAngle = 1.7 * Math.PI;


function init()
{
    //Clear the canvas everytime a chart is drawn
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H)

    //Background 360 degree arc
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = bgcolor;
    ctx.lineWidth = 30;
    ctx.arc(W/2, H/2, 100, startAngle, endAngle, false); //you can see the arc now
    ctx.stroke();

    //gauge will be a simple arc
    //Angle in radians = angle in degrees * PI / 180
    var radians = degrees * Math.PI / 1030;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.lineWidth = 30;
    //The arc starts from the rightmost end. If we deduct 90 degrees from the angles
// CHANGE THIS LINE HERE
    //the arc will start from the left
    ctx.arc(W/2, H/2, 100, startAngle, radians - 180*Math.PI/180, false); 
    //you can see the arc now
    ctx.stroke();

    //Lets add the text
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.font = "50px bebas";
    text = Math.floor(degrees/720*100) + "%";
if (text < "25%") {
    color = redcolor;
} else if (text > "25%") {
  color = yellowcolor;
} else if (text > "75%") {
  color = greencolor;
}
    //Lets center the text
    //deducting half of text width from position x
    var text_width = ctx.measureText(text).width;
    //adding manual value to position y since the height of the text cannot
    //be measured easily. There are hacks but we will keep it manual for now.
    ctx.fillText(text, W/2 - text_width/2, H/2 + 15);
}

function draw()
{
    //Cancel any movement animation if a new chart is requested
    if(typeof animation_loop != undefined) clearInterval(animation_loop);

    //random degree from 0 to 360
    new_degrees = Math.round(Math.random()*360);
//new_degrees = 721;
    difference = new_degrees - degrees;
    //This will animate the gauge to new positions
    //The animation will take 1 second
    //time for each frame is 1sec / difference in degrees
    animation_loop = setInterval(animate_to, 1000/difference);
}

//function to make the chart move to new degrees
function animate_to()
{
    //clear animation loop if degrees reaches to new_degrees
    if(degrees == new_degrees) 
        clearInterval(animation_loop);
    if(degrees < new_degrees)
        degrees++;
    else
        degrees--;



    init();
}

//Lets add some animation for fun
draw();
redraw_loop = setInterval(draw, 2000); //Draw a new chart every 2 seconds




}
```

You can see the code at http://codepen.io/rgaspary/pen/Glfdn

Comment: Now why the hell would you not just use an integer value instead of putting a `%` in there and comparing strings?

Comment: You should try to check the degrees in an integer format instead of string format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using strings instead of numbers.  As a result, the comparison is alphanumeric instead of a number comparison.

For example, the **string** `"9%"` comes after the string `"25%"`.

Comment: Precisely. Solution would be to just use numbers: `var red = 25;` etc. and remove `+ "%"` from assignment to `text`.

Comment: Yes, this worked. I can't belive I did not see that. I'm going to get some coffee now :/

Thank you so much for your help. I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if synchronosity is the culprit, but...

using `setInterval()` is generally a bad idea.

Use `setTimeout()`, and when your `draw()` function finishes executing, call it recursively with another `setTimeout()`.

Comment: This portion of the code is going away once I implement it, I needed it here just to see the animation.